# What does exclaimation point symbol mean for files during XCode commit?

Tags: ios, xcode

When committing changes to an SVN repository from within XCode some of the files have the "!" symbol in the right column (see screen capture).

[image]

What does this symbol mean and what should I do w/ these files? It seems to be any time a file is deleted from the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the file is known to the version control system, but missing or damaged locally.  Here's a list of SVN status codes:

http://knaddison.com/technology/svn-status-code-cheat-sheet

Often the solution to this problem is to go into the folder containing these files, and remove the `.svn` folder from it.  In particular, this should work if the problem started happening after you copied/imported folders/files from another project (already under version control) into your current project.  The issue is that the `.svn` folders are not portable cross project/repository.  Trying to import a `.svn` folder from somewhere else just causes the version control system to get confused.

Comment: I don't see any folders names ".svn". Are they hidden? Do I have to change some setting to see them?

Comment: I figured out how to find and remove the .svn folder. Now I can't commit the files I've changed to SCC. I get the message "Unable to load revisions". Seems like the project is no longer under SCC?

Comment: Did you delete all the `.svn` folders from the entire project, or just the one in the folder that contained the problematic files?  In any case, the easiest way to fix things at this point might be to 1) back up your current working folder, 2) check out the latest repository version to a new location, 3) copy over the files (not the folders) that you have modified into the new checkout location, 4) commit your changes, 5) overwrite your current working folder with the latest version in the repository.